# Find the word length in $G=\langle S|R \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider the group $G=\mathbb Z^2$ generated by $S= \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} \pm 2 \\ \pm1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \pm 1 \\ \pm 2 \end{bmatrix} \right \}.$ In other words, the generators are moves that can be made by a chess knight. 
>   What is the length of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}?$ (Recall that the word length in $G=\langle S|R \rangle$ is defined by letting $|g|$ equal to the shortest "spelling " of $g$ in letters from the alphabet $S$). 
>   b) Consider the group $G=\mathbb Z^2$ generated by $S=\left \{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right \}.$ 
>   How many group elements $g$ have $|g| \leq n$, where $n=2,3,4$? Sketch the Cayley graph that shows $|g| \leq n$.

a) We have $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$, so the length is less than or equal $3$. How to show that it's actually $3$. The only thing that comes to my mind is just showing that the length is not $1$ or $2$ by brute force.Any other ways to deal with this? 
b)  I think that the Cayley graph should look like a lattice and the elements with $|g| \leq n$ lie in the diamond with length $2n$? Is there any way to count the number of elements inside the diamond?

Comment: What do you mean by $|g|$? I usually read this as the order of an element (i.e. the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $ng = e$), but since $ng = n[a,b]^T = [na,nb]^T$, it means $ng = 0$ for $n > 1$ iff $a = b = 0$, so I assume you mean something else.

Comment: @CookieMonster, it is the shortest path in the Cayley graph to spell the element in $G=⟨|⟩  $ using letters from the alphabet $$).